# Accessing DOM element of a webpage without opening it

Tags: javascript

I have started working on JavaScript.  I want to count the number of frames/anchors on yahoo homepage without opening it(means I don't want to load the page in another window or frame). I didn't find a proper solution for this without using AJAX.Can't we create a document object referring to remote page?
As I am using JavaScript without any framework, can someone guide me how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean "without opening it"?

Comment: How would you imagine that examining the contents of some random web page can be done without the page being "opened"?  You could delegate that task to YQL, but **something** has to fetch and analyze the page contents.

Comment: Most of the solutions I found on internet was suggesting to open the remote page in a window and the access the document object of that window to get the number of elements. I hope it is clear now. I just want a script on my page which directly display number of frames on yahoo homepage.

Comment: Let me know whether it is feasible or not? 
If feasible then do I need to use AJAX for this?

Comment: It's not, at least not with Javascript. With PHP for example you could read the page in, do a regex count on how many times the desired tags occur and pass that to your client. But it's nasty and totally not resource-efficient.

Comment: @pointy By "without opening" I meant,  without loading the page in different window or frame . Can't we create a document object referring to remote page??

Comment: @rtcoms no, that is not possible with JavaScript.  In order for a web browser to create a DOM, it must access the page.  Browsers will not allow JavaScript from a page in one domain to observe the contents of a page in another domain. That work must be done by server-side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have very few options if you're working on the client side only. This is primarily because you'll be dealing with the dreaded, but necessary, cross-domain policy. However, even if you don't have cross scripting issues, it won't be possible to accomplish this without AJAX. You'll need to make a request to a server for the page's HTML somehow. I would suggest taking a look at [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) as it appears to solve the cross-domain issue.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to execute an HTTP request to get the HTML string to feed into a DOM object.  AJAX is the easiest way to do that, why do you want to avoid AJAX?

In plain old Java you can create a DocumentBuilder and source a document with a URL, but I don't believe this is available in javascript.